# La aplicación que configure en android studio no se abre después de descargarla de play store

Tags: android-studio

soy nueva en la programación, y he subido una aplicación a play store, pero una vez que las descargo en el celular no se abre. Cuando estuve probando en el emulador, funcionaba bien, pero al descargarlo no. No se porque sucede esto.

[image: Adjunto build.gradle]

Comment: Puedes pegar el codigo en lugar de colocar una imagen?

Comment: A que código te refieres?

Comment: Me tope con esta pregunta en las colas de revicion. No la lei bien, Crei que eso era el codigo de la aplicacion. No trabajo con android, pero mas bien parece un archivo de configuracion. De todos modos, el codigo que consideres relevante, es mejor que  lo pegues en vez de colocarlo en una foto.